# Confused in SQL query involving "Null" return no row selected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, null

I'm confused by the result of the two SQL queries. Give the table content and two queries:

```
Col1 Status
---- ------ 
abcd "null"
abcd PENDING
defg "null"
defg PENDING
```

`a) SELECT Col1, STATUS FROM TABLE_A WHERE KEY IN ('abcd','defg');`

`b) SELECT Col1, STATUS FROM TABLE_A WHERE KEY IN ('abcd','defg') and NOT (STATUS = 'PENDING')`

result of (a) shows all 4 rows, and result of (b) shows nothing!

Column 'Status' can have values other than 'PENDING', and for reporting reason, I cannot use 'STATUS IS NOT NULL' as filter. I CANNOT understand why query (b) return nothing. Thanks in advance for any help

Platform: MSSQL 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL uses three valued logic (`True`, `False`, `Unknown`). The `WHERE` clause needs to evaluate to `True` for a row to be returned.

`STATUS = 'PENDING'` returns `UNKNOWN` when `Status IS NULL`.

If you negate `Unknown` you still get `Unknown`.

See [SQL and the Snare of Three-Valued Logic](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/)

You would need to rewrite the query as

```
SELECT Col1, STATUS 
FROM TABLE_A 
WHERE KEY IN ('abcd','defg') and (STATUS IS NULL OR  STATUS  <> 'PENDING')
```

(Though it is possible to use the deprecated `ANSI_NULLS` session option to get the behaviour you want)

Comment: +1 but as OP can't seem to use `STATUS IS NOT NULL` for one reason or another, you might change the condition to `AND NOT ISNULL(STATUS, '') = 'PENDING'`

Comment: @Lieven - A possibility but I'm not sure why the OP has added that restriction into the question. If they can't change the query at all then they could look at `ANSI_NULLS`.

Comment: they could... but I wouldn't want to maintain it :)

Comment: Maybe the OP can explain the parameters they are working under so we don't have to try to second guess them!

Comment: Thanks very much for information about "null" comparison in "where clause". I have came out a workaround to my original problem.